# Algorithm for Gaussian random field generation via Karhnunen--Loeve expansion

Tags: random-sampling

I have difficulty understanding how to generate a Gaussian random field from Karhunen--Loeve expansion.

Precisely, I need to generate a zero-mean field with covariance function $C(x, y)$. We find eigendecomposition of $C(x, y)$ from the equation:

$$
\int_0^1 C(x, y)\, e(y)\, \mathrm dy = \lambda \,e(x)
$$

I discretize the above equation in the following way. For grid $0=x_0 < \dots x_I=1$ with $I+1$ points and the grid size $1/I$, I use midpoint method to obtain

$$
\frac1I \sum_{j=0}^I C(x_{i+1/2}, y_{j+1/2}) \, e(y_{j+1/2}) = \lambda \, e(x_{j+1/2})
$$
which can be compactly represented as matrix eigendecomposition problem for matrix $\frac1I C$:
$$
\frac1I C e = \lambda e
$$
$C \in \mathbb R^{I\times I}$, $e \in \mathbb R^I$, $\lambda \in \mathbb R$. Solving this problem, we obtain $I$ eigenvalues and eigenvectors, and then approximated random field is
$$
\kappa(x, \omega) \approx \sum_{k=1}^N \sqrt(\lambda_k) y_k(\omega) e_k
$$
where $y_k(\omega)$ are standard Normal Gaussian variables.

The problem that I have is that the generated random field is sensitive to the grid size $I$, and I do not understand where the problem is and how to fix it.

Comment: What do you mean by sensitive? I would expect approximations to get better as you use more grid points. Do you observe divergence?

Comment: Also "Numerical methods for the discretization of random fields by means of the Karhunen–Loeve expansion" by Wolfgang Betz et al. is one of the most cited pieces of literature on approximating KL expansions of Gaussian random fields that I know of. Check that to see what may have gone wrong.